# I want to store all the dictionaries in the list but when I try to do this it stores only the last dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

```
#imports
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import pandas as pd

#Loading the Data File

tree = ET.parse('abc.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
list1=[]
finalData=[]
#Function Which Will Progressively Extract Data From the XML File
def xmlPand(list,result=None):
    result = [] if result is None else result
    for item in list:
        if (item.getchildren()):
            ListofChildren=[]
            for child in item:
                ListofChildren.append(child)
            #print ListofChildren
            xmlPand(ListofChildren,result)
        else:
            dicto[item.tag]=item.text
    result.append(dicto)
    print dicto
    #here when i print it takes all different values the way I want but when    I append it to the list and print the list it gives me only the last dictionary that has been created a number of times



#Getting All the Schema Tags in a list  
for child in root:
    list1.append(child)

#Creating a Temp List for each Schema Tag and Sending it to the xmlPand     Function   

for item in list1:
    list2=[]
    data=[]
    list2.append(item)
    dicto={}
    xmlPand(list2,result=data)
    print data
```

What it did here was it kept on adding stuff to the dictionary but overlapped it with the latest
Note that the XML file has many hierarchies
I just need a way to store the dictionaries that have been created in a list.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with your comments on what you are adding to what and where?

Comment: I am taking the values i.e from an xml document, I am trying to store it in a dictionary for example, if there is an xml document like 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<shiporder orderid="889923"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
  
  <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
  <address>Langgt 23</address>
  <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
  <country>Norway</country>
</shiporder>  
  Now here ship order is the root node then I will take all those child tags in which there is text and store in a dict

Comment: And then try to store every dictionary I create in a list progressively. If you run the above program and run the "print dicto" line it will consider every dictionary that is created but if you try to store it in a list as I am using the data.append(dicto) it will just store the last dictionary created

Comment: I will store it in the dictionary in such a way that the child.tag is the key and child.text is the value. So every immediate child node of the root will be stored in a dictionary. If you can please run the code by commenting the "print dicto" line you can get what I am saying. Actually I want to store whatever the "print dicto" is printing into a list(data=[] in this case).